# How filter out middle portion of URL when building Google Analytic segments?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a page I want to exclude from a GA segment, like this:

mywebsite.com/apply/XXXXXXXXX#!/rates_terms

where XXXXXXXX is some random generated number.

Originally I was just excluding any URL with "rates_terms" in it.  But then I realized we also have a page like

mywebsite.com/rates_terms

And I don't want to exclude that page.

I tried doing a Regex, like "/apply/.*/rates_terms", but it definitely missed almost everything.

What other Regex code can I try?  I wonder if the shebang is throwing GA off.

Thanks!

Comment: OK I figured it out.  Apparently in GA, the page shows up as "/apply/rates_terms", dropping the random # in the middle.  So I can just exclude on this.

Comment: If the issue is no longer repro, you can remove the question.